# How to scroll text with seekbar?

Tags: android, textview, scrollview, seekbar

I am learning Android Studio and I am making program where is very much text so I am trying to make it scrollable with seekbar (also I want it to be vertically scrollable) seekbars 0 amount is top and 100 is bot. I made it so that is scrolls when seekbars is moved but I can't figure how to make it so that it is related to lenght of my text.
Here is code in my MainActivity.Java:

```
    seek_bar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    text_view =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    seek_bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(
            new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                int progress_value;
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                    progress_value = progress;
                    TextView newtext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                    ScrollView hscrollViewMain = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollViev);
                    newtext.setText(hscrollViewMain.getMaxScrollAmount().toString()); // I made this because I thought that it would tell me the maximum amount of pixels in my text but toString() doesnt work somehow. It is redlined :(
                    hscrollViewMain.scrollTo(0, (hscrollViewMain.getMaxScrollAmount()/100)*progress_value); //this scrolls only little when seekbar is moved
                }
```

And here is my activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:weightSum="1">

<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/seekBar" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollViev"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:fillViewport="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
    android:isScrollContainer="false">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/testtext"
            android:id="@+id/textView2" />

        <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:text="@string/maintext" />
</LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have also thought using computeVerticalScrollRange() method instead of getMaxScrollAmount but because it is protected method, I don't know how to use it. I am pretty stucked here so any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opninion you can do in this way:

1) create a Relativelayout on the left/right of you Seekbar

2) create a TextView inside this RelativeLayout

3) now you have to get the height of the RelativeLayout. To do that you can use onMeasure/onLayout(but in this way you have to implement your custom RelativeLayout) or simply a ViewTreeObserver

4) now you have the height of both your components so make you calculations

5) every time you move the SeekBar you have to "update" TextView position. Inside a RelativeLayout you can set the position using `children.layout(left, top, right, bottom)` and then call `invalidate()` on the TextView to update it.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for response! Sorry for this taking too long but there was powercut in my area and I don't program on Sundays. But anyway I made Scrollview with child object relativeview. Inside that there is seekbar and textview but the thing I don't get is how to use this onMeasure/onLayout. I mean they are both protected methods and I have this in code RelativeLayout Relativelay = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.Relativel); That isn't custom RelativeLayout, am I right? I tried to search from Internet about using protected methods in Java but didn't really get how to do it.

Comment: To get the layout measure you need to use ViewTreeObserver http://www.limbaniandroid.com/2014/10/viewtreeobserver-how-to-get-layout.html

Comment: Thanks man! (y) that solved problem. Didn't work straight but with little modification it did what I needed. If someone else is struggling with same problem, I removed this line this.layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this); It made layout red and then I added final to this: final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);